# Adding a working Clock and Refreshing form in Access

Tags: forms, ms-access

Is there any way that I can add a working clock in the form that increments every second and its main or sub form to refresh every minute?

I have this code as of the moment:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    With Me
        .Requery
    End With
    MsgBox "Refreshing"
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Timer()
    Me.Auto_Time.Requery
End Sub
```

and set its event on its form properties:

[image]

If I change its time interval to `60000`, the form is refreshed every minute but if it's `1000`, the time is the only updated one every second. Is there any way I can update the time every second and the form every minute?

Comment: In the timer event you can save the last form refresh time and you could check if the last form refresh was more than 60 seconds before... What have you tried so far?

Comment: @SebastianSchulz I didn't get your point. The above codes is what I've tried.